# How to add associations to models in rails

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I have three models

```
class SupplierVariant

  belongs_to  :supplier
  belongs_to  :variant

end

class Supplier

  has_many :variants, :through :supplier_variants

end

class Variant

end
```

Now I want to know, how to get supplier of a particular variant.I added an association 
  `has_one :supplier through: :supplier_variant`  in Variant class

but when I do the following query I get below mentioned error

```
p=Spree::Variant.find(384)

  Spree::Variant Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "spree_variants".* FROM "spree_variants" WHERE "spree_variants"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "spree_variants"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 384]]
 => #<Spree::Variant id: 384, sku: "CHG137-Blue-XL", weight: #<BigDecimal:a396b38,'0.5E3',9(27)>, height: #<BigDecimal:a396a20,'0.5E2',9(27)>, width: #<BigDecimal:a3968e0,'0.45E2',9(27)>, depth: #<BigDecimal:a396778,'0.75E2',9(27)>, deleted_at: nil, is_master: false, product_id: 228, cost_price: #<BigDecimal:a3962c8,'0.9E3',9(27)>, position: 4, cost_currency: "INR", track_inventory: true, tax_category_id: 3, updated_at: "2015-05-25 05:58:19", stock_items_count: 4> 

p.supplier
**NoMethodError: undefined method `supplier' for #<Spree::Variant:0x0000000a3973a8>**
```

How to add proper associations in model folder in rails? and How to use them after we add it?
 Does applying join operation between tables depend on the associations we define in models?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the appropriate association to your `Variant` class, e.g. `has_many :suppliers, :through :supplier_variants`. Right now it's just an empty class with no methods, thus the undefined method error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Michael. Does join between tables depend on associations we define in models?  and why was it not working when I added association  has_one :supplier, :through :supplier_variant?

Comment: @Shakthi You have to declare the associations in both directions. Your Supplier knew about your Variant but your Variant knew nothing. This just the way Rails is.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SupplierVariant

  belongs_to  :supplier
  belongs_to  :variant

end

class Supplier
  has_many :supplier_variants
  has_many :variants, :through :supplier_variants

end

class Variant
  has_many :supplier_variants
  has_many :suppliers, :through :supplier_variants
end
```

Correct the associations of these models.

```
@variant = Variant.last
@suppliers = @variant.suppliers
```

It willl give you suppliers of particular variant.